# How can you get a powershell to list the permissions of folders within a directory while ignoring groups that have access?

Tags: powershell

I'm still relatively new to Powershell and have been working on this for a bit off and on.

We have a couple of shared drives, and I'm trying to find a list of all individual users who have access to folders within, but ignoring groups & any system users.

Here's what I've been trying to use so far (using the simplest way possible, testing on my desktop)

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\default\Desktop\TestFolder" -Directory |
  Get-ACL  |
  Where IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" |
   Format-Table -Wrap
```

This does not hide the "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" from the output of the folders within "TestFolder". I've tried a few iterations/different ways to go about it but keep having the same issue.

I also have no idea how to hide groups from the output.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: The problem is that *IdentityReference* is a sub-property of *Access*. Therefore, you need to  expand that objects property first, then filter: `gci "C:\Users\default\Desktop\TestFolder" -Directory |
  Get-ACL  | select -exp access | Where IdentityReference -NotLike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Please post this as answer (and since this is a new user, I suggest you do not use cmdlet aliases ;)

Comment: @Theo, just wanted to make sure that's what they're after lol but, thank you. Will do!

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment...

The solution would be to *expand* the correct property of *Access*, and then filter by the property of *IdentityReference*; since this is just a *sub-property*:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\default\Desktop\TestFolder" -Directory | 
    Get-Acl |
    ForEach-Object -Begin `
    {
        $toExclude = "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM|BUILTIN\\"
    } -Process `
    {
        $Directory = $_.Path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::","") 
        $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Access" | Where-Object -Property "IdentityReference" -NotMatch $toExclude |
            Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "Directory" -Value $Directory -PassThru
    }
```

Here, we make use of `|` in `$toExclude` to denote the separation of "*or*" values to use against our `-NotMatch` operator.

- `-NotMatch` operator uses [Regular Expressions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) (also known/shortened as *RegEx*), which allows us to use such delimiter.
- Just like the *Begin* block in functions, this will only run once for the entirety of the expression/command. This makes it ideal to place preparations like `$toExclude` there if you're not going to place it before your command.
- The *Process* block will run once **per** object in the pipeline unlike the *Begin* block, and this is where we put the logic in our code.

After the filtering out of the unwanted values, using `Add-Member`, we can add the current directory by referencing the current object in the pipelines property of *Path* adding it back to the object, and passing it down the pipeline with `-PassThru`.